# How to verify color of a web element in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, safari

I am looking to identify the text colour of a particular class within a div (ie. Red or green) is there any way to use WebDriver to do this ? I have found alternatives that use openqa.selenium.WebDriver; and subsequently .getcssvalue. Would it be possible to use .getattribute ?

Pls help stuck for days now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python's selenium webdriver this should suffice: `.value_of_css_property(property_name)` Where property name would be 'color' I believe. Docs can be found [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.value_of_css_property)